# sse instruction access violation

Tags: memory, sse

I am new to SSE instruction and trying to learn it. I wrote a small program as follows, but gave me an access violation error. It might be because of the memory misalignment, but I have a hard time to find out exactly what is wrong with it.

```
void add_sse(uint16_t *a, uint16_t *b { 
  __m128i *av = (__m128i*)a;    //16-byte aligned (128 bits)
  __m128i *bv = (__m128i*)b;
  __m128i cv = _mm_setzero_si128();
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
     cv = _mm_adds_epu16(av[i], bv[i]);
     _mm_store_si128(av + i, cv);
  }
}

int main(){
  uint16_t a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
  uint16_t b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

  add_sse(a, b);

  int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(uint16_t);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I also tried another way to do `add_sse()` and found out that it worked some time, but did not work most of time. Here is the code:

```
void add_sse(uint16_t *a, uint16_t *b) {
    *(__m128i*) &a[0] = _mm_add_epi16(*(__m128i*)&a[0], *(__m128i*)&b[0]);
    *(__m128i*) &a[8] = _mm_add_epi16(*(__m128i*)&a[8], *(__m128i*)&b[8]);
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to Peter's comment. I got it working now. Just post it to make sure whoever has the similar questions gets the answer. This is what I got:

```
void add_sse(uint16_t *a, uint16_t *b) {
  __m256i av = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)a);
  __m256i bv = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)b);
  __m256i sum = _mm256_add_epi32(av, bv);
  _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)a, sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require your inputs to be aligned, you have two main options:

- do scalar ops until the address is aligned, and then do an aligned vector loop.
- use the loadu and storeu intrinsics.  Their main purpose is to communicate alignment info to the compiler, so it can use the appropriate load instructions (the one that works with unaligned, or the one that faults on unaligned).  (And for float, casting between float* and `__m128`, but the int load / store intrinsics don't even cast for you.)

Comment: Ha, I see. OK I used the second method and got it working! Thank you!